# tiles 2.1: nesting templates 3 levels deep - attribute isn't replaced

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles2

I see PLACEHOLDER on result page instead of edit.jsp page content. Source of tiles-defs.xml listed below.

```
<definition name="layout" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="body">
        <definition template="/WEB-INF/tiles/user/layout.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="userMenu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/user/menu.jsp"/>
            <put-attribute name="userContent">
                <definition template="/WEB-INF/tiles/user/profile/layout.jsp">
                    <put-attribute name="profileNav" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/user/profile/nav.jsp"/>
                    <put-attribute name="profileContent" value="PLACEHOLDER"/>
                </definition>
            </put-attribute>
        </definition>
    </put-attribute>
    ...
</definition>

<definition name="editUser" extends="layout">
    <put-attribute name="profileContent" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user/auth/edit.jsp"/>
    ...
</definition>
```

Also tried to split in 3 separate definitions without any result. Also played with cascade attribute without any result too.

Answer (score 1):

Pls. add to top of `/WEB-INF/tiles/user/profile/layout.jsp`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
```